# Type trait that checks whether function parameter can be initialized by a certain type

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to refactor a function interface that uses Boost_PP by using variadic templates.
The interface allows to register function objects. In pseudo code this looks like this:

```cpp
template<typename F, 
         typename ReturnValue, typname Arg1, ..., typename ArgN,
         typename Example1, ..., typename ExampleN>
void registerFunction(F&& function, 
                      std::string parameterName1, std::string parameterDescription1, Example1 e1, ...., 
                      std::string parameterNameN, std::string parameterDescriptionN, ExampleN en);

float rectangleArea(const float width, const float heigth);

registerFunction<float, const float, const float>(&rectangleArea, 
                                "width", "width of rectangle", 2,
                                "height", "height of parameter", 4);
```

I tried to replace the Boost_PP created function with:

```cpp
template<typename F, typename ReturnValue, typname ... Args, typename ... Description>
void registerFunction(F&& function, Description&& ... desc);
```

However, every third element must be so that if forwarded to the `function` the object is callable.
Eg. in pseudo code:

```cpp
function(std::forward<Description2>(desc2),std::forward<Description5>(desc5),.....)
```

I tried to use SFINAE to restrict my function to valid descriptions.

```cpp
template<typename Args, typename Descriptions, typename Enable = void>
struct ParameterParser: std::false_type
{};

// recursion end
template<typename Enable>
struct ParameterParser<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<>, Enable>: std::true_type
{};

template<typename Argument, typename ... RemainingArguments, typename Name, typename ParameterDescription, typename Example, typename ... RemainingDescription>
struct ParameterParser<std::tuple<Argument, RemainingArguments...>, 
                       std::tuple<Name, ParameterDescription, Example, RemainingDescription...>, 
                       typename std::enable_if<
                           (sizeof...(RemainingArguments)) * 3 == sizeof...(RemainingDescription)
                            && std::is_convertible<Example, Argument>::value
                            && std::is_convertible<ParameterDescription, std::string>::value
                            && std::is_convertible<Name, std::string>::value>::type> 
      :ParameterParser<std::tuple<RemainingArguments...>, std::tuple<RemainingDescription...>>
{};

template<typename ArgumentTuple, typename DescriptionTuple>
using ValidDescription = typename std::enable_if<ParameterParser<ArgumentTuple, DescriptionTuple>::value>::type;

template<typename ReturnValue, typename ... Args, typename ... Description, typename F,
         typename = ValidDescription<std::tuple<Args...>, std::tuple<Description...>>>
void registerFunction(F&& function, Description&& ... desc)
{

}
```

However, it seems like `std::is_convertible<Example, Argument>::value` is not the correct trait for my use case.
The problem is the following:

```
void functionToRegister(int&);

// this won't compile
registerFunction<void, int&>(&functionToRegister, "a parameter", "a description", 1);
```

The `1` is deduced as `int` and `std::is_convertible<int, int&>::value` is false.

How can i express a condition between two types 'ARG' and 'CallOBJ' that says: the parameter `a` of a function `f(ARG a)` can be initialized with something of type `CallOBJ`.

Note that i am limited to C++11 :(

Here is a godbold link to my problem:
https://godbolt.org/z/PMGon1f8q

Comment: Is your question just "how do I express that if a parameter is an lvalue reference like `int&`, my trait should still work with a temporary like `1`"? If so the answer might be [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) or [`std::add_lvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference).

Comment: `typname` is a typo and the `...` in `typename Arg1, ..., typename ArgN,` is not valid syntax. Also as pseudo code it is not clear what that `...` should be. Pleae try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Nelfeal more ore less. The question is, as written: How can i express a condition between two types 'ARG' and 'CallOBJ' that says: the parameter a of a function f(ARG a) can be initialized with something of type CallOBJ.

I just wanted to provide background in case i missed something obvious in my use case.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai it is not valid syntax. Valid syntax would require to provide the whole boost_pp mess which would blow up the question considerably without providing more insight in the problem.

Comment: you do not have to provide a mess to fix `typname` into `typename` and to remove `...` when they are not needed for the question

Comment: @Mehno The problem with your question (that you just repeated in your comment) is that `1` is something of type `int`, not `int&&`. It is however an rvalue. Which is why I'm asking if the true question is that the trait should work with a temporary, aka an rvalue.

Comment: @Nelfeal you are right, it will be deduced a such using perfect forwarding. The question remains the same cause `std::is_convertible<int, int&>::value` is also false

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai i fixed the typename type. I will not fix the ... pseudo code cause it is important for the context.

Comment: no need to argue. I looked at your code, tried to compile it, then added the includes, tried to compile again, get a wall of errors unrelated to the question https://godbolt.org/z/79cKTMqMe, dropped a comment, because I assume others will feel similar frustration. The `typname` and `...` was only the first details I spotted, but tehre is more. You dont *have to* fix anything, but it would help others to answer the question.

Comment: Can you change prototype of the function to `registerFunction(F&& functioNamedParameter<Ts>...)`? (group linked parameter).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai i provided a godbolt link.

Comment: @Jarod42 i am afraid that is not possible. The interface is exposed as part of a library and existing code must still compile. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a precise answer since you don't specify what [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) should work. However, if your only issue is that you want `std::is_convertible<Example, Argument>::value` to be true even if `Argument` is a lvalue reference and `Example` is not, then adding [`std::add_lvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) to the first type (`Example`) should do the trick:

```
std::is_convertible<typename std::add_lvalue_reference<Example>::type, Argument>::value
```

It also works if `Example` is a reference (lvalue or rvalue), though it does not work if `Argument` is a rvalue reference.

If you want this extra case to work as well, you can use [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) instead:

```
std::is_convertible<typename std::remove_reference<Example>::type, typename std::remove_reference<Argument>::type>::value
```

Comment: i provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Mehno a couple of `typename`s was  missing but then your example compiles fine with the suggestion from this answer https://godbolt.org/z/3Yjrj99r4

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm not sure you want to use `is_conv` for the string parameters.

Comment: It seems to work with all combinations i have so far. If i stumble upon a combination that still gives an error i will update this question accordingly. Thx :)

Comment: @Mehno The only additional cases I can possibly imagine (though I can't give an example) would be solved with [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) and [`std::remove_cv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv).

Comment: @Nelfeal `std::remove_cv` should be used with care. Otherwise it would deduce that it is possible to initialize an `int&` with an `const int&`

Answer (score 1):

Even if you cannot change prototype, I would create a more friendly prototype:

```
template <typename T>
struct NamedParameter
{
    std::string name;
    std::string desc;
    T example;
};

#if 1 // CTAD (for clang)
template <typename T>
NamedParameter(std::string, std::string, T) -> NamedParameter<T>;
#endif

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
void registerFunction(F&& f, NamedParameter<Ts>... parameters)
{
// ...
}
```

Then the function to expose old interface:

```
// Easy SFINAE, noexcept might be added too
#define Return(...) decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { return (__VA_ARGS__); }

template<typename Ret, typename... Us, typename F, typename... Ts>
auto oldRegisterFunction(F&& f, Ts... args)
-> Return ([]<std::size_t...Is, typename Tuple>(std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Tuple t){
       registerFunction(f,
           NamedParameter<Us>(std::get<3 * Is>(t),
                          std::get<3 * Is + 1>(t),
                        std::get<3 * Is + 2>(t))...);

    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args) / 3>(), std::forward<F>(f), std::tie(args...)))
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GahchqW5c) (done with C++20)
For C++11,

- `index_sequence` should be implemented.
- lambda should be turned into regular template function.
- use the C++11 fold expression workaround.

Comment: That is a great answer that i like a lot. Might consider trying that approach (altough it might have a bit overhead in c++11). Thx